# Leniency in journals' paper structure "guidelines" (required sections and divisions)

Tags: journals, formatting

I have observed in the "author ***guidelines***" of journals, that results and discussion may be requested as

- distinct `"results"` and `"discussion"` sections,
- or as combined `"results & discussions"`.

In particular, more qualitative observation based topics tend to prefer the latter, while direct quantitative measures that may be the dominant tool in the field may be the impetuses of choosing distinct sections.

Has anyone had any experience with journals and just how rigid they may be when it comes to the hierarchical distinction/formatting of results and discussion sections?

My thoughts are that a journal may be more willing to separate the sections than to combine. But I am trying to gauge whether it will even be worth approaching the journal to inquire whether they would consider a manuscript with a combined `"Results & Discussion"` sections.

Comment: Which field? I've never found an author guideline specifying section titles.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I am working on a paper that is to provide a translational product to a surgical/clinical audience from a non-medical field. Here is a snippet from a possible target journal that I believe is rather explicit in it's request:  `The text of a Research Article should be organized as follows: Title page, Abstract, Introduction, Methods, Results, Discussion, Acknowledgments, References, Tables, and Figure legends.`

Answer (score 5):

I hate it when a journal decides to stretch you on a [Procrustean bed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procrustes#Cultural_references) of arbitrary structure, since many research projects simply do not fit on such.  Some really want you to fit their arbitrary structure, while others will bend, and it's not really possible to know which is which and how much flexibility you've for unless you talk to an editor.

That said, I've often found that with a little bit of mental gymnastics in how you approach "results and discussion" you can generally make things work.  Consider, for example, [this decently-cited paper of mine](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/sb300030d), which didn't really fit the "intro - results - discussion - methods" format desired by the journal, since it was *about* a (fairly complex) method.  Well, if you think of the method as *being* the result, then we essentially shove the whole paper as we wanted to structure it into the "results & discussion" section, with our preferred structure as subsections.  The "methods" section then contains all of the boring details about protocols for the validation tests that we ran.

Bottom line: often a journal really means it about its structure requirements, but that actually constrains you less than you might think.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have access to the article from home, I will check it out from work tomorrow. Indeed I will also have an interesting challenge of choosing what belongs in either a methods or results section, but more perplexing, is the difficult way of describing images in a completely non quantitative way without turning to much into the discussion itself.

Answer (score 2):

So, I received some suggestions from some colleagues who had some useful information that ultimately resolved my problem.  So for posterity, here's how my conundrum was resolved.

> Look through the current issue (and work your way back) to determine
>   the prevalence of the the scenario your seeking to resolve.
>   Then follow up with the journal if your proof feels weak or insufficient.

In my case I found 3 examples spread out over 10 years.  Not a strong positive, but it at least has been approved in the past.  This may imply, however, that this was an exception granted special permission.  Since there's no way to figure this out, I decided that I wouldn't face the same level of reluctance from the editors if I contacted them with a question about what they would accept.  In fact, despite my expectation that they would be irritated having to address this question, they were kind and enthusiastic.

Guess with so many journals these days the competition between some is tight and they want your business.